# How to search for string that is on it's own a single line in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to search a robots.txt file for the string "Disallow: /", but that string must be on its own line like in the example below. At the moment it's finding others which is not what I want.

The string could "Disallow: /" could also have a space or number of spaces after it.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// File from http
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http  s://domain.com/robots.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$handle = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);   
//echo $handle;

$find = "Disallow: /";

if (strpos($handle, $find)){ 
    echo "Found" ; 
} else{ 
    echo "Not Found"; 
}
```

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /  << to find this
Disallow: /c/portal/. << my code picks up this if the above line is missing.
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /*/wp-admin/
```

Comment: Either split the content into individual lines first and then loop over them, so that you can check each for equality; or use a regular expression (which gives you the ability to "anchor" your search pattern at the start and end of subject lines.)

Comment: @M.Eriksson Good point, was a bit simplistic wasn't it. I will get more coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle it.

#### Using regular expressions:

You can use regular expressions to find a match:

```
if (preg_match('/^Disallow: \/(\s+)?$/m', $handle) === 1) {
    echo 'Found';
} else {
    echo 'Not found';
}
```

- `^` asserts position at start of a line
- Disallow:  matches the characters Disallow:  literally (case sensitive)
- `\/` matches the character `/`
- 1st Capturing Group `(\s+)?`

  - `?` matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
  - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
  - `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line
- `m` modifier at the end: multi line. Causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

*(Explanation taken from [https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BsSugu/1))*

---

#### Without regular expression

You can explode the string into an array, with each line as an array item and check if the array contains the string you're looking for:

```
// Create an array with each line as an array item
$handle = explode("\n", $handle);

// Run rtrim() on each line to remove any trailing white spaces
$handle = array_map('rtrim', $handle);

// Check if the string exists in the array
if (in_array('Disallow: /', $handle)) {
    echo 'Found';
} else {
    echo 'Not found';
}
```

---

Here's a demo of both: https://3v4l.org/Bovta

Comment: I got a vote down, so I'm wondering how I can better describe my question.